# Angular CLI, can't create a new project because of an invalid configuration file was found

Tags: linux, angular, terminal

This error appear when I try to create a new angular project with the command `ng new app-new`
I have this error on the following picture :

[image: error picture]

So I tried to uninstall and install again angular, and research this file but it's not in the directory. 
Do you know what can cause this error please ?

Comment: Please show the code and/or state the errors. Please don't use links to images. The text is missing from the question. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. The text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors. Also see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an "error" with the Angular CLI, but a config file at a level it probably shouldn't be. `/home/shirley/.angular.json` is listed in the error, and the error suggests that you delete it. If you don't need that file for anything else you're working on, delete the file. If you do need the file, Angular CLI won't work at this level.

```
ls -a /home/shirley/ <-- file is in here
rm /home/shirley/.angular.json <-- remove it
```